# How to achieve synchronized deployment of Frontend and Backend applications to PRD?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, devops, aws-sam

I'm new to web apps and trying to deploy one to production which consists of:

1. React App on Frontend (deployed on AWS S3 + Cloudfront)
2. Python (Flask) AWS Lambda + API Gateway on the backend (deployed using AWS
   SAM)

Both FE and BE have separate repositories. After testing the latest versions of FE and BE on staging env, I want to deploy to production without any downtime.

When deploying it may happen that FE is updated from FE_V0 -> FE_V1 but BE_V0 is not updated to BE_V1 and vice-versa. During this time FE_V1 will have an incompatible BE and will not function. It may also happen that FE_V1 is successfully deployed but BE_V1 deployment fails and will result in a longer downtime.

What strategy and services do you employ for the synchronized deployment of FE and BE apps? The ideal situation will be to:

1. Deploy FE_V1 and BE_V1, while FE_V0 and BE_V0 are still active.
2. Switch the customer-facing application to (FE_V1 + BE_V1) together or redirect the traffic incrementally from V0 to V1 combination.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot work because you have cloudfront cache, which mean you would have users from FE_V0 calling BE_V1.

What I think you should do is **versioning your api gateway**, so your FE_V0 calls BE_V0 and your FE_V1 calls your BE_V1 and so on.
Doing so your application will be *always* available.